# prove the answer of CX=0 might not be the answer of AX=0 or BX=0

Tags: linear-algebra

if A  and B are $n\times n$ matrixs, also AB=BA=C. How to prove prove the answer of  homogeneous linear equations CX=0 might not be the answer of AX=0 or BX=0?

Answer (score 1):

For $n=2$ let $A=B=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$. Then $C$ is the null matrix.